# UITapGesture target not retained (with ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, gesture

I create an UITapGesture with a target which is NOT the current object. Later, when tapping, app crashes.

View controller .h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *iv;
}
@end
```

View controller .c:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Target.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Target *t = [[Target alloc] init];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:t action:@selector(gestureDone:)];
    [iv addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
    [iv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}

@end
```

Target.h:

```
@interface Target : NSObject

- (void)gestureDone:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr;

@end
```

Target.c:

```
@implementation Target

- (void)gestureDone:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    NSLog(@"Gesture!");
}

@end
```

(My XIB file just contains one image...)
When tapping the image, it crashes. If for example I add an instance variable Target *t to my view controller (and remove local declaration in viewDidLoad), then no issue arises. When not doing that, I overrided dealloc in Target, put a NSLog there and saw that as soon as viewDidLoad finishes execution, the Target object is fred.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is it some issue? (Usually I'm not facing this problem because I use initWithTarget:self ...).

Comment: can you add the crash log please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't retain its target.  Most objects that take a target/action pair do not retain their targets.  This is mentioned in the [*Cocoa Fundamentals Guide*/Communicating with Objects/The Target-Action Mechanism/The Target](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW31):

> Control objects do not (and should not) retain their targets. However, clients of controls sending action messages (applications, usually) are responsible for ensuring that their targets are available to receive action messages. To do this, they may have to retain their targets in memory-managed environments. This precaution applies equally to delegates and data sources.

You need to make sure the target is retained some other way, such as by storing a reference to `t` in an instance variable of your `ViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had figured out. Would you have any official reference about that? I searched before posting here and couldn't find anything stating it would not retain.

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance variable of the Target `t` to your `ViewController` class and make it strong. That way it stays in memory.